# How to use z-index and flexbox together

Tags: html, css, flexbox, position, z-index

`I tried to use z-index and flexbox together for the logo image and navigation bar but I guess because of position: absolute, the flexbox function doesn't work.
I want to know the solution for how I can resolve this problem.

[image]

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

input {
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: 0.5px solid black;
  background-color: transparent;
}

input:active {
  border-color: transparent;
}

.input-area {
  margin-left: -20px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

/*
At this point, I add the z-index and it 
seems like to conflict with the flexbox. 
*/

.logo {
  margin-left: -2rem;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 500;
}

.top-nav {
  margin-right: 4rem;
  font-size: 11px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 150;
}

.side-nav {
  margin-top: 2rem;
  margin-left: 5rem;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: grey;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 150;
}

.my-carousel {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<!-- 
Here I used justify content: flex-end for change the position 
of navigation bar, but after I used the z-index function, 
it doesn't work 
-->

<div class="top-nav">
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-end">
    <ul class="nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">LOGIN</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">JOIN</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">CS</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#"><input class="input.underline" type="text" id="search_form" name="keyword" class="top_srarch_text" title="" placeholder="" autocomplete="off" </a>
          <span class="input-area">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass" style="color: #a5a8ab;"></i>
          </span>
          <span class="ml-5">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-cart-shopping" style="color: #a5a8ab;"></i>
          </span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<!--logo-->
<div class="logo">
  <nav class="navbar bg-transparent">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="https://cdn-pro-web-228-207.cdn-nhncommerce.com/olchitr4058_godomall_com/data/skin/front/mime_left_C/img/banner/1bb87d41d15fe27b500a4bfcde01bb0e_37200.png" alt="Bootstrap" width="auto" height="auto">
      </a>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>

<div class="side-nav">
  <ul class="nav flex-column">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#"><img src="https://cdn-pro-web-228-207.cdn-nhncommerce.com/olchitr4058_godomall_com/data/skin/front/mime_left_C/img/common/btn/btn_allmenu_open.png" /> </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">NEW</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">TOP</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">OUTER</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">ALL-IN-ONE</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">HARNESS</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">ACC</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">LIVING</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="my-carousel">
  <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide">
    <div class="carousel-indicators">
      <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
      <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
      <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
      <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="3" aria-label="Slide 4"></button>
      <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="3" aria-label="Slide 5"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img src="./carousel/bag.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="./carousel/camping.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="carousel/econature.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="carousel/five dogs.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="carousel/roundbag.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
      </div>
    </div>
    <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
      </button>
    <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
      </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `position: absolute` moves an element out of the flow. It will then be placed to the next relative parent element which by default is only the body. Since you did not assign a positioning value (top, right, bottom, left), try using `position: relative`